# Regex: remove any chars or numbers before a needle

Tags: regex

I am about to build a regex pattern to extract a number from a string which is unknown and can be different every time..

Because it is always unknown how my string looks, here a some common examples:

1. 12cm iamtext 311
2. iamtext 311 12 cm iamtext 311
3. iamtext 311 12cm

Summed up: What I am aiming for is the number before `cm` or `cm` (space). This pattern can show up with a undefined amount of numbers. So, it could also be something like `12414 cm`. In this case I want to get the `12414`.

But if there is something like `iamtext311 cm` I don't want to get anything back cause in this case the number belongs to the text. But if there is a space between the number and the text, I want to get the `311`.

This is what I got so far:

```
.*?\d+.*?(\d+)
```

But this isn't working for chars.. and I don't know how to process at the moment.. Cause it is such a complex situation especially with all the different cases with and without a space...

Would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem.

- The number is obtained with the obvious `\d+`.
- You don't want it preceded by any character but spacing characters: `(?<!\S)`.
- Must be followed by an optional space then characters `cm`: `(?=\s?cm)`.

Put it together: `(?<!\S)\d+(?=\s?cm)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9nhqlM/1).

Comment: Thanks mate, thats what I am shooting for! - Nice explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

How about that with `\b` with optional `space` character?

```
\b\d+\s?cm\b
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/10

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `.*?\d+.*?(\d+)` you don't account for the `cm` part.

What you might do instead is assert the start of the string or match 1+ times a whitespace character and use a capturing group for the digits.

To prevent cm to be part of a longer word, you could add a word boundary `\b`:

```
(?:^|\s+)(\d+) ?cm\b
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3r0DS/1)

If you don't want to match newlines using `\s+` you could use a character class to match a space and/or a tab `[ \t]`